# In galois field- how does modular arithmetic

Tags: cryptography

The following is given in the text that I have: 
In $GF(2^8)$ [Galois Field]
let: $$h(x)=x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$$
$$x^8 \bmod h(x)= [h(x)-x^8]$$
I basically don't understand the second step
I think $h(x) mod x^8=[h(x)-x^8]$, is the text mistaken or am I ? If I am please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $x^8\equiv x^8-h(x) \bmod h(x)$, namely $h(x)\mid (x^8+h(x)-x^8)$. On the other hand, since $2=0$ we have $h(x)-x^8=x^8-h(x)$.

Comment: since 2=0? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: The characteristic of the field $GF(2^8)$ is equal to $2$. By definition then, $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The leading terms of $x^8$ and $h(x)$ are the same so that the quotient is $1$, and both

$$x^8=h(x)+(x^8\bmod h(x))$$ and $$h(x)=x^8+(h(x)\bmod x^8)$$ hold.

Comment: but is h(x)modx^8=x^8mod h(x)

Comment: @mathmaniage: this is precisely shown by my answer !

Comment: I don't know, but, is the answer no? I came to the conclusion: (h(x)modx^8)=-(x^8modh(x))

Comment: @mathmaniage: you are in $FG(2^8)$.